# While loop in Java bytecode using ASM 4.0 does not work

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm writing a compiler for a language in Java bytecode using ASM 4.0. Executing the program causes it to crash. The relevant part of a stack trace is following:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
```

The problem is in a code for a while loop:

```
Label start = new Label();
Label end = new Label();

methodVisitor.visitLabel(start);
generateCodeForACondition(condition, methodVisitor);

methodVisitor.visitJumpInsn(IFEQ, end);
generateCodeForABody(ws.getBody(), methodVisitor);
methodVisitor.visitJumpInsn(GOTO, start);

methodVisitor.visitLabel(end);
```

Fun fact: the code for my if/else statement is very similar to that of a while loop, however the if/else code works and the while loop code doesn't. It means that the methods generateCodeForACondition and generateCodeForABody both work properly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you compiling using Compute_Maxs or Compute_Frames? If you're using frames try Maxs and see what the bytecode looks like. Sometimes you miss little mistakes that aren't too obvious until runtime.

Comment: Since `Frame` has no method named `a`, I suppose you are using an obfuscated version of the ASM library. Switching to a standard, i.e. not obfuscated, version and regenerating the stack trace could help.